# javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation while calling a method in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to pass an attribute from a given bean to a method which returns the first addressee of a given email, identified by its ID. It's my first time with JSF and I don't really know if I'm doing something wrong when passing the "email.id" as a parameter, but when trying to edit an email this is what its shown in the page.

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException:
>   /restricted/editmail.xhtml @31,68
>   value="#{emailController.getFirstAdressee(email.id)}": Illegal Syntax
>   for Set Operation

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputText required="true"
                 requiredMessage="#{msgs.name_requiredMessage}"
                 validatorMessage="#{msgs.name_validatorMessage}"
                 id="addressee"
                 value="#{emailController.getFirstAdressee(email.id)}">
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message for="addressee"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Why are you using a parameterized getter method here `value="#{emailController.getFirstAdressee(email.id)}"`?

Comment: To retrieve the addessee of a given email, and show it in the textfield, so the user can add another one, or modify the one already there. It's like editing a draft.

Comment: But that should happen at another place such as a method decorated with `@PostConstruct` or whatever that makes sense.

Comment: Hm... to create a variable in the controller, get the data in the init() (@PostConstruct) method and assign it to that variable so I can just do emailController.addressee and retrieve what has been assigned to it previously? (I just realised that I should retrieve all of them, so the method there is the wrong one also)